# Can you statically set a Header with a value from $context (AWS API GATEWAY)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to get the caller user from AWS_IAM auth before hit my http endpoint.

I was trying to pass $context.identity in the request body adding a mapping template in the integration request but my http endpoint is a GET request and i was getting an empty request body.

I need to know which one of my user is making the request

Maybe passing $context.identity.cognitoIdentityId as a request header is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the $context variable does not currently work in request headers, only in mapping templates.  We have a feature request to add this in the future, but no estimated deliver date yet.

Using $context.identity.cognitoIdentityId does work in a mapping template, but as you pointed out, API Gateway won't send the request body to the backend endpoint for a GET request.

As a temporary workaround, can you change the backend endpoint to use a POST or a PUT?

Then you could pass the 
I'm surprised the $context.identity.cognitoIdentityId in the mapping template for the body.

Comment: Do you have a link to the feature request so we can track when it gets implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround until this gets fixed is to use Lambda as another proxy. You could use the mapping template to send `$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId` to a Lambda function. The function then forwards the request to your http endpoint with the relevant context fields in the header instead of the body. This way you don't have to change your API (you can continue to use GETs etc.).

I've posted [more details and an example of a generic function here](http://ruhkopf.name/blog/aws-api-gateway-http-proxy-lambda-workaround). Hope it helps.